# suitable parser required for parsing xml data in a google app engine for java - web app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xml-parsing

I am working to parse XML data in a java web application on Google App Engine.

I started out with Xstream, however it uses some classes that are restricted by Google App engine.

Can you suggest a parser that is fully compatible with Google App Engine for Java, and has a small learning curve/plenty of examples/tutorials?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully used the java sax parser within GAE. It is pretty simple once you get going with it. Basically as it is reading in your document it calls functions that you specify that deal with the data in the xml. Its not for every application but its really fast and easy on memory.

Here is a great tutorial / intro article for it:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/